# Accuracy and Loss do not change while training LSTMs

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, loss-function

I am trying to train a text classification model using LSTMs. During training the accuracy and loss do not change. I would be grateful to know anyone has faced a similar problem and how they were able handle it. please find the code segment as below :

```
def define_model5(embeddings_matrix,vocab_len, max_wc):
    dl_inputs= Input(shape=(max_wc,),dtype='int32')
    embedding_layer =  Embedding(vocab_len,50,weights=[embeddings_matrix],trainable=False)(dl_inputs)
#    LSTM_layer_1 = LSTM(64,dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5, return_sequences=True)(embedding_layer)
    
    LSTM_layer_1 = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(embedding_layer)
    dropout_layer_1 = Dropout(0.5)(LSTM_layer_1)
    LSTM_layer_2 = LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)(dropout_layer_1)
    LSTM_layer_3 = LSTM(16)(LSTM_layer_2)
#    dense_layer_0 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(LSTM_layer_3)
#    dense_layer_1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(dense_layer_0)
#    gpool_layer_1 = GlobalMaxPool1D()(LSTM_layer_2)
#    dense_layer_1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(gpool_layer_1)
    dense_layer_1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(LSTM_layer_3)
    model = Model(inputs=dl_inputs,outputs=dense_layer_1)
    print(model.summary())
    return model

   X_train,Y_train=load_data(TRAIN_FILE_PATH)
    X_test,Y_test=load_data(TEST_FILE_PATH)
    X_train, X_test, embeggings_matrix, vocab_len, max_sen_len = create_embeddings(X_train, X_test)
    #define model
    model = define_model5(embeggings_matrix, vocab_len, max_sen_len)
    #Compile the model

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    #opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.001)

    model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
    # Train the model - with evaluation
    es_cb=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=2)
    hist= model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=32, verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),callbacks=[es_cb])
```

I have tried changing the number of nodes, increasing layers, adding dropout, change learning rate, changed batch size and tried different optimizations functions (SGD and Adam) to no avail. The initial accuracy and loss figures may change a little but they do not change during training.